# jQuery: Select region of table

Tags: jquery, select, html-table

I have a scenario where I would like to select a region of 2 `td`'s from a column table at a time

I have a table like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>R1:C1</td>
    <td>R1:C2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>R2:C1</td>
    <td>R2:C2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>R3:C1</td>
    <td>R3:C2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>R4:C1</td>
    <td>R4:C2</td>
</tr>
```

And I would like for example to select cells `R1:C1` and `R2:C1` whether I hover on one of these two and when I hover on `R3:C1` or `R4:C1` it would select cells `R3:C1` and `R4:C1`.

So basically, it would threat a table with 4 rows and 2 columns like a table with only 2 rows and 2 column

Edit: I want to threat a group of x cells in a row like one so I could apply event listeners on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use classes for  to select right cells for example

```
<tr>
<td class="group1">R1:C1</td>
<td>R1:C2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="group1">R2:C1</td>
<td>R2:C2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="group2">R3:C1</td>
<td>R3:C2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="group2">R4:C1</td>
<td>R4:C2</td>
</tr>
```

And jQuery to change background on hover

```
$('.group1').hover(
    function(){$('.group1').css('background-color','black');}, 
    function(){$('.group1').css('background-color','white');});
$('.group2').hover(
    function(){$('.group2').css('background-color','black');}, 
    function(){$('.group2').css('background-color','white');});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Oh, how come I didn't think of that? Much easier than I imagined, thanks.